# After installing Ubuntu 15.10 text,photo,video gets broken or shattered

Tags: graphics, display, 15.10

[image: Display gets broken displaying images]

[image: Video gets blurry with broken shadows and layers.]

Image gets broken, video gets blurry with layers and text look something alien language. When I select something sometimes it fixes temporarily. Blur happens on lost focus, and gets normal again whenever something is redrawn. (There is a chance that the image I've uploaded it appears normal to you, but shattered for me.)

I hadn't this problem while using Ubuntu 14.10.  It's aching after upgrading to 15.10. [{I had this problem solved on previous 15.10 intall by installing a linux package with some numbers that suggested to solve it temporarily. But that solved my problem entirely.}] I slightly remember that it may load settings of previous versions.

```
My pc details: Intel Core 2 dual processor,
               Intel hd graphics adapter,
               3 gb ram.
```